# How do I reset the password on a Dedicated Micros DVR?

Tags: security, video, dvr

I have an ECO 9 Dedicated Micros DVR unit. This specific one has 9 analog video cards. Some guides suggest the username is `dm` and the password is `web`, other guides say the username is `username` and the password `password`. Regardless, I don't know it. How do I reset it?

The guide specifically says,

> These default usernames and passwords should be changed as soon as practical to maintain security. Always make a note of the new passwords, as these cannot be reset easily. A unit will have to be returned to the manufacturer to have a password reset.

Comment: According to the guide, `A unit will have to be returned to the manufacturer to have a password reset.`  I think that means you have to return it to the manufacturer to have the password reset.

Comment: Regardless of what the manufacturer says, I've proven that is not the case. I just did it. That's why I self-answered and contributed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you only lost the web access username and password, try to telnet into it with the the username `dm` and the password `telnet`. **This will reset all of the users**

Then run the following commands,

1. cd etc
2. del user.db
3. reset

If telnet is echoing every character and you see double of every character you type, ignore it and march on. The unit takes a while to reset, but then you're all good and ready to go with username `db`, and password `web`.

### Caveat

This will reset all of the users,

- **dm** (Web Page Configuration) / **password "web"**
- **dm** (Video FTP) / **password "ftp"**
- **dmftp** (Admin FTP) / **password "ftp"**
- **dm** (Telnet) / **password "telnet"**
- **dmconsole** (Serial) / **no default password**

to their defaults passwords. [source](http://www.dedicatedmicros.com/europe/file.php?path=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fvhosts%2Fad-group.co.uk%2Fdedicatedmicros.com%2Feurope%2Ffiles%2Fsupport_docs%2Fuk%2Ff2316&filename=Password%20Note%20(v42_003).pdf)

Comment: a) This only works in the unlikely event that you somehow lost the web password but not the telnet one and b) this is technically not a password reset, this is how you delete all the users on the local device (or so it appears).

Comment: @HopelessN00b it resets all their passwords. It does not delete the users. I've updated with that caveat.